# Sandbox not extended when dragging URL from Finder

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsurl, appstore-sandbox

I'm implementing drag and drop from the Finder into a NSTableView.
It works fine, except that I can not (always) access the referenced file.
The (test) validation method is as follows:

```
-(NSDragOperation)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView validateDrop:(id<NSDraggingInfo>)info proposedRow:(NSInteger)row proposedDropOperation:(NSTableViewDropOperation)dropOperation {
    NSArray *newURLs = [info.draggingPasteboard readObjectsForClasses:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSURL class]]
                                                       options:@{NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey:@YES}];
    for (NSURL *url in newURLs) {
        if (![url startAccessingSecurityScopedResource])
            NSLog(@"failed");
        [url stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
    }
}
```

This logs `failed` for the URLs received.

I receive the (file reference) URLs just fine from the Finder (their `path` is what I expect it to be).

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001288-101258) states that dragging NSURL objects should work, so I'm a bit surprised that this doesn't work.

What's the correct way to drag URLs from the Finder to my app?